# How do I check if a value has changed, whilst my program is running?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

One of the value of my program might be change while other function is processing, Once the value has changed, the program should launch a particular function.
How do I let my program know the value has changed when the program is running? Pls help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And which version of Xcode are you really using? And which language?

Comment: try listening for the new value and writing the changed value to console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Key-Value Observation is what you want. This will allow you to observe the value of a property, and be notified when it changes.

Documentation + guide can be found here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA